# Pause For each until finish Thread inside C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm in trouble with this code. I'm using .Net (C#) with Winform Application.

I have foreach loop for files inside directory and with each file I want to run thread with some functions.. the problem here is the loop not waiting for the thread to finish and the result is if I have 5 files, I get 5 threads run with each other making my pc freeze .. is it possible to pause the loop until the thread finish, then continue the loop for other threads ??

```
foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(txtPath.Text))
{
    Thread threadConversion = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(function name));
    threadConversion.Start(function parameter);
}
```

Comment: Why not use Parallel instead??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to read the files sequentially, why not move the whole thing inside the thread?

```
Thread threadConversion = new Thread(() => {
    foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(txtPath.Text))
    {
        //read file f
    }
});

threadConversion.Start();
```

Or better yet, use Tasks:

```
await Task.Run(() => {
    foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(txtPath.Text))
    {
        //read file f
    }
});

//do some other stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

You just don't need to run the method as a thread. Just run it like this:

```
foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(txtPath.Text))
{
    function(parameter);
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing the OP wants to read files from another thread not to freeze the UI thread.

Comment: He should run the whole foreach in another thread then. Since there are no UI activities this should be no problem.

Comment: Just like you suggested in your answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.100).aspx) method ( you must at least the version .net 4.0)

**For example**

```
 Parallel.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(txtPath.Text), f=>
                {
                 //some code
                }
                );
```

Comment: @speising you are right :) thanks, I correct my answer